# elasticsearch default credentials

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-x-pack

i've found that the default credentials for ES are elastic:changeme but it's not working for me! am i missing something?
the error :

```
{
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
        {
            "type": "security_exception",
            "reason": "failed to authenticate user [elastic]",
            "header": {
                "WWW-Authenticate": "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""
            }
        }
    ],
    "type": "security_exception",
    "reason": "failed to authenticate user [elastic]",
    "header": {
        "WWW-Authenticate": "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""
      }
   },
  "status": 401
}
```

Comment: can you add the elastic query , you are executing

Comment: any request... i'm also trying those on the browser on localhost:9200

Comment: if you are using browser try http://elastic:changeme@localhost:9200/, if on curl curl -XPUT -u elastic:changeme 'localhost:9200' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'

Comment: nothing works!!

Answer (score 1):

i have found the solution :

just run the command bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto -u "http://localhost:9200" on cmd and passwords will be regenerated and printed in the console.